# Unhide block of four rows without currentStage

Tags: excel, vba, show

I'm a beginner in coding and specially with VBA. I have an Excel document on which several rows are hidden. I need to unhide the row 34:37, 42:45, 50:53, 58:61, one block of four rows at a time, until they are all unhidden. I have a button made out of a shape.

For now, I have a `currentStage` function applied to the code, but it's counterproductive, since I don't want the code to hide rows, only unhide.

Here's the code for now :

```
Sub UnhideObjectives()
Static currentStage As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        .Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 1)
        .Rows("50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 2)
    End With

currentStage = (currentStage + 1) Mod 3
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unhide all rows in one operation:

```
Sub UnhideObjectives()
    ActiveSheet.range("A34:A37,A42:A45,A50:A53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Edit: OK I see what you mean

```vb
Sub UnhideObjectives()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.Range("A34:A37,A42:A45,A50:A53").Areas
        If rng.EntireRow.Hidden Then     'is this block hidden?
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide
            Exit For                     '...and stop looping
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, but is it possible that the block of four rows unhide one block at a time, so each time I click on the button made out of a shape, a block of four rows unhide.